# console.log not working in Angular2 Component (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, angular

I am relatively new to both Angular2 and typescript. Since typescript is a superset of javascript, I'd expect functions like `console.log` to work. `console.log` works perfectly in `.ts` files when outside a component class but does not work as I'd expect from inside the component class.

```
// main.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
console.log("Hello1"); //1. This works perfectly

@Component({..)
export class App {
 s: string = "Hello2";
 // console.log(s); //2. This gives compilation error (when uncommented)
 // Error: Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.
}
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: what did you put in the @Component?

Can you try and put a constructor in the class like this:

constructor() { console.log('test')}

Comment: i think it's not working because console.log is not wrapped in a function. can you show the JS  compiled form ?

Comment: @L.querter: console.log is working when it's used inside the constructor but doesn't work when used outside the constructor even if constructor is present. Maybe wrapping it in a function is necessary. I wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It's not working because console.log() it's not in a "executable area" of the class "App".

A class is a structure composed by attributes and methods.

The only way to have your code executed is to place it inside a method that is going to be executed. For instance: constructor()

```js
console.log('It works here')

@Component({..)
export class App {
 s: string = "Hello2";
            
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.s)            
  }            
}
```

Think of class like a plain javascript object.

Would it make sense to expect this to work?

```js
class:  {
  s: string,
  console.log(s)
 }
```

If you still unsure, try the typescript playground where you can see your typescript code generated into plain javascript.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Comment: A variable initialization is also an expression and I am confused why that works outside the constructor's scope and function calls do not.

Comment: Try that typescript playgroung I mentioned above, you'll see that every variable definition is transpilled to a javascript function body.

Comment: something so obvious and I was starting to go crazy trying to solve this - thanks

Comment: In the javascript example you gave, it still makes no sense that s:string, console.log(s) shouldn't return at least some value. It should at least say in the browser s is of type string.

Comment: Wow, in an hour of searching, this answer finally made it click in my mind. Thank you! Angular newbie here.

Answer (score 7):

The `console.log` should be wrapped in a function , the "default" function for every class is its `constructor` so it should be declared there.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
console.log("Hello1");

 @Component({
  selector: 'hello-console',
})
    export class App {
     s: string = "Hello2";
    constructor(){
     console.log(s); 
    }

}
```