# how to log messages in e2e protractor test cases in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I want to use `console.log()` inside my protractor e2e test case for angular2.

```
import { HomePage } from './home.page.ts';
describe('App', () => {
  let homePage;
  beforeEach(() => {
    homePage = new HomePage();
    browser.get('/#/home');
  });

  it('should find the nested class using a page', () => {
    let addElem = element(by.css('.add-btn'));
    console.log(addElem);  // I tried this, but it doesnt work .I am expecting this can be logged in console 
  })
})
```

any inputs?
thanks.

Comment: Where do you want to print the output of `console.log()`? In the terminal or in the browser console?

Comment: in browser console only @d_z90

Comment: Have you tried placing it in a component? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869496/console-log-not-working-in-angular2-component-typescript

Comment: @d_z90 I dont want to print it inside component, I am running a protractor  test , where I have calculated few expressions, those I want to log in browser console.

Answer (score 1):

The method `console.log` is executed synchronously, so you need to push it in the control flow:

```js
function log(arg) {
  browser.call(function() {
    console.log(arg);
  });
}
```

```js
let addElem = element(by.css('.add-btn'));
log(addElem);
```

Comment: It says protractor.browser does not have any controlflow property

Comment: I tested it with v4.0.10 and it works as expected. Check the source for`controlFlow`: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/4.0.10/lib/browser.ts#L40. Note that you could also call `browser.call`. See update.