# Node.js + Vue.js: why is console.log() in vue.js files not showing in console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, vue.js, console.log

I'm new to javascript development and I have a real project here. Let me describe:

1. There is a project, an Express (Node.js) server that has a /public/app folder
2. There is another project, a Vue.js app that has a /dist folder
3. In the Express /public/app folder is copypasted vue.js application (copied from another project from /dist folder)
4. Vue.js app runs at http://localhost:3000/app/#/

I've added some console.log() commands into a different files/places in a vue.js app code, for example:

**app.ts**

```
...
import {store} from './store/store';
import {isBoolean} from 'util';

console.log('APP');

let router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: WelcomeComponent },
...
```

or in **component**:

```
...
import * as common from '../../../store/common';
import * as country from '../../../store/country';

console.log('COMPONENT');

@Component({
  template: require('./template.html'),
  components: {
    'layout': LayoutContent2,
...
```

and so on. But none of the console.log() messages are displayed in a browser console. Im sure that an app is builded and copied correctly. So why can't I see the messages in console?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869496/console-log-not-working-in-angular2-component-typescript

Comment: No, not really! In that case already works what does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that Windows was not replacing the old main.min.js file with the new one. After manually removing and copying the files again it works!

Comment: Try to to do a hard reload